# AutoCompleteTextView: want to filter character from the list that would be matched from the left to right not any character inmiddle

Tags: android

I am using AutoCompleteTextView in my android application. When typing character in textview then matched any positions character that is available in the list. But I want to filter character that would be matched from the left. Thanks in advance.

```
Following is my code:
**Layout:**
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/txtCustName" 
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLines="1" 
android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:dropDownSelector="#a0b4f0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

**Code:**
        AutoCompleteTextView txtCustName=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCustName);
        txtCustName.setAdapter(C.getArrayAdapter("Select CHEM_NAME||', '||Add1||'::'||CHEM_CODE from Chemist"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `Adapter` which implements [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html), in the `getFilter()` method . Check this [link](http://www.sacoskun.com/2008/08/autocompletetextview-with-simpleadapter.html), Use `String.startsWith()` for your requirement

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:dropDownSelector="#a0b4f0"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />


    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    String arrayItems[] = new String[]{"abcdef","bcdef","cdef","def","ef","f"};
    ArrayList<String> filterItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

    class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


        public Adapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return nameFilter;
        }

        Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                return resultValue.toString();
            }
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                if(constraint != null) {
                    filterItems.clear();
                    for(int i=0;i<arrayItems.length;i++){
                        if(arrayItems[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                            filterItems.add(arrayItems[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = filterItems;
                    filterResults.count = filterItems.size();
                    return filterResults;
                } else {
                    return new FilterResults();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<String> filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    clear();
                    for (String c : filteredList) {
                        add(c);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };

    }
```

Comment: Link is not showing any solution. Can you please share another link?

Comment: It's working fine. Many Thanks. But now How do I change the text color of List item. It's showing white.

Comment: then please upvote and flag my answer...
there is another overriden method getView() inside the custom adapter. You can use this to change the text color of List item.

Comment: List showing very slow compare to default properties. How do I make it faster?